# how to merge list of arrays and each element in one array into list of tuples in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, tuples

So in python, I have list of arrays that looks like

```
    [array([628,  688,  924, 1598], dtype=int32), 
    array([ 957, 1983, 2031, 2429], dtype=int32),
    array([1243, 1598, 2872], dtype=int32)]
```

and an array that looks like

```
    array([1, 2, 3], dtype = int32])
```

I want to merge the 2 into list of tuples, or something like this.

```
    [(array([628,  688,  924, 1598], dtype=int32), 1), 
    (array([ 957, 1983, 2031, 2429], dtype=int32), 2),
    (array([1243, 1598, 2872], dtype=int32), 3)]
```

Would anyone help me on coding this?

Thanks!

Comment: ```list(zip(list1, arr1))``` should do it.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about using zip but didn't think about using list(zip())!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`You can use zip()`:

```
a = [array([628,  688,  924, 1598], dtype=int32), 
    array([ 957, 1983, 2031, 2429], dtype=int32),
    array([1243, 1598, 2872], dtype=int32)]
b = array([1, 2, 3], dtype = int32)          # there was an extra ] here
c = list(zip(a, b))
```

Result:

```
[(array([ 628,  688,  924, 1598], dtype=int32), 1),
 (array([ 957, 1983, 2031, 2429], dtype=int32), 2),
 (array([1243, 1598, 2872], dtype=int32), 3)]
```